# Trig Substitution quadrant diagram Confusion

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Evaluate $\, \displaystyle \int _{-1}^{-1/2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt {4x^2-1}}$.

$My\ work:-$

substituting $\, \displaystyle 2x=\sec (\theta),\, \,$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle  \displaystyle \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(2x)^2-1}} \displaystyle = \displaystyle  \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{ \sec (\theta )\, \tan (\theta )\, d\theta }{\sqrt{\sec ^2(\theta )-1}} $

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \int \frac{ \sec (\theta )\, \tan (\theta )\, }{2\, |\tan (\theta )|} \,  d\theta$

now since$\displaystyle \, -1\leq 2x = \sec (\theta )  \leq -\frac{1}{2}\ $ we have quadrant II and III where $\sec (\theta )\leq 0.\,$

$Question:-$ 
 1. In solution they given a diagram for IIIrd quadrant and Yes i know when we calculate sec we get same 2x, but i am confused how'd they come up with this diagram ?

[image: Solution Set]

and here's my Diagram, it will really  helpful if someone please point out mistakes in my diagram

[image: My workings]

sorry for such Naive question

Comment: $\sec \theta = 2x \implies \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2x}$ and then use $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ to find $\sin\theta$. That explains their diagram.

Comment: @MathLover stupid question, but my diagram is also representing $\sec \theta = 2x$

Answer (score 1):

You have made mistake in your second step . You denoted $ 2x = \sec { \theta}$ .
As $x \ge {-1} $, $2x \ge {-2}$ , therefore , $\sec { \theta} \ge {-2}$ . Therefore , $\cos { \theta} \le {{-1} \over 2}$. Now proceed.

Comment: $x = \frac{\sec (\theta )}{2}\ $ now its alright ??